# How to create a Percona XtraDB cluster in Docker swarm on multiple nodes with persistent data

Tags: database, docker, docker-swarm, percona

I want to setup a PXC cluster in Docker Swarm with persistent data in production environment.

My Ansible code looks like:

```
version: '3.7'

services:
  pxc_cluster:
    image: percona/percona-xtradb-cluster:5.7
    hostname: pxc_cluster
    environment:
      - CLUSTER_NAME={{ db.cluster_name }}
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD={{ db.root_pass }}
      - MYSQL_DATABASE={{ db.percona.prod.name }}
      - MYSQL_USER={{ db.user }}
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD={{ db.pass }}
    deploy:
      mode: replicated
      replicas: 1
      restart_policy:
        condition: on-failure
        delay: 5s
        max_attempts: 3
        window: 120s
      update_config:
        parallelism: 1
        delay: 10s
        failure_action: continue
        monitor: 30s
    networks:
      - percona-net

{% for n in range(1, 4) %}
  pxc{{n}}:
    image: percona/percona-xtradb-cluster:5.7
    hostname: pxc{{ n }}
    environment:
      - CLUSTER_NAME={{ db.cluster_name }}
      - CLUSTER_JOIN=pxc_cluster
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD={{ db.root_pass }}
      - MYSQL_DATABASE={{ db.percona.prod.name }}
      - MYSQL_USER={{ db.user }}
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD={{ db.pass }}
    depends_on:
      - pxc_cluster
    volumes:
      - hdb_data{{ n }}:/var/lib/mysql
    deploy:
      mode: global
      restart_policy:
        condition: on-failure
        delay: 5s
        max_attempts: 3
        window: 120s
      update_config:
        parallelism: 1
        delay: 10s
        failure_action: continue
        monitor: 30s
      placement:
        constraints:
          - node.labels.env == prod
          - node.labels.percona == pxc{{ n }}
    networks:
      - percona-net
{% endfor %}

  adminer:
    image: adminer
    deploy:
      restart_policy:
        condition: any
    networks:
      - percona-net
      - vpn-net

networks:
  percona-net:
    name: name_percona-net
  vpn-net:
    external:
      name: name_vpn-net

volumes:
{% for n in range(1, 4) %}
  hdb_data{{ n }}:
    driver: local
{% endfor %}
```

but the problem is that if the server with pxc_cluster is going down then the cluster will go down also. It will not matter if the server will become reachable as the cluster will be gone.
Also, if the pxc_cluster has persistent data this will not help also.

What can I do to have a cluster with 3 databases on 3 different nodes for HA?

Regards,

Astin

Comment: I founded a solution at https://hub.docker.com/u/bitc0d

Comment: So I’m using these images and seems to work great